# Get the frequency count using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this

```
genrename   subgenre    subgenrename    actor
Songs       208             Dance    Aamir Khan
Songs       208             Dance    Aamir Khan
Songs       211            Romantic  Aamir Khan
Movies       1             Romantic  Aamir Khan
Songs       208             Dance    Aamir Khan
Clips        15             Scenes   Aamir Khan
Clips        15             Scenes   Aamir Khan,Salman
Clips        12            Romantic  Salman
```

The output dataframe that that i am trying to get would look something similar like this

```
Actor_Name songs    clips   movies
 AmirKhan   4          2    1
SalmanKhan  0          2    0
```

Can somebody guide me on this with pandas or any other data processing libraries python have?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with column `actor`, [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original. Then [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with `aggfunc=len`, [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
s = df.actor.str.split(',', expand=True).stack()
s.index = s.index.droplevel(-1) 
s.name = 'actor1' 
df = df.join(s)


print df.pivot_table(index='actor1', 
                     columns='genrename', 
                     aggfunc=len, 
                     values='subgenre',
                     fill_value=0).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)

       actor1  Clips  Movies  Songs
0  Aamir Khan      2       1      4
1      Salman      2       0      0
```

Comment: Sorry, give me a time.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, don't forget accept it. Thanks.